# How can I combine conditionals in Ansible when one is an "in" type conditional?

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I can't seem to combine two conditionals of the form `"'foo' in bar"` and `boolean_thing|bool` together using the `or` operator like this:

```yaml
- name: Notify if a or b
  command:
    cmd: find_a
  register: result
  changed_when: "'A is here' in result.stdout" or b_is_true|bool
  notify:
    my_a_or_b_handler
```

That throws:

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key
[helpful indication of where the error was]
The offending line appears to be:

  register: result
  changed_when: "'A is here' in result.stdout" or b_is_true|bool
                                                  ^ here
```

Note that well-documented conditional combinations of the form `a|bool or b|bool` work of course.

Also note that `and` suffers from the same malady. But there's a way to work around that:

```yaml
- name: Notify if a and b
    command:
      cmd: find_a
    register: result
    changed_when: 
      - "'A is here' in result.stdout" 
      - b_is_true|bool
    notify:
      my_a_and_b_handler
```

I think that might be cheating.  :)

At any rate, it does not solve the `or` dilemma.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task and handler below do the job

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Notify if a or b
      command:
        cmd: "{{ playbook_dir }}/find_a"
      register: result
      changed_when: ('A is here' in result.stdout_lines) or (b_is_true|bool)
      notify: my_a_or_b_handler
  handlers:
    - name: my_a_or_b_handler
      debug:
        msg: Handler notified
```

---

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    b_is_true: false

  tasks:
    - name: Notify if a or b (True or False)
      command:
        cmd: "{{ playbook_dir }}/find_a"
      register: result
      changed_when: ('A is here' in result.stdout_lines) or (b_is_true|bool)
      notify: my_a_or_b_handler
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout_lines
    - meta: flush_handlers

    - name: Notify if a or b (False or False)
      command:
        cmd: "{{ playbook_dir }}/find_b"
      register: result
      changed_when: ('A is here' in result.stdout_lines) or (b_is_true|bool)
      notify: my_a_or_b_handler
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout_lines
    - meta: flush_handlers

    - set_fact:
        b_is_true: true
    - name: Notify if a or b (False or True)
      command:
        cmd: "{{ playbook_dir }}/find_b"
      register: result
      changed_when: ('A is here' in result.stdout_lines) or (b_is_true|bool)
      notify: my_a_or_b_handler
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout_lines
    - meta: flush_handlers

  handlers:
    - name: my_a_or_b_handler
      debug:
        msg: Handler notified
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [Notify if a or b (True or False)] ****
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.stdout_lines": [
        "A is here"
    ]
}

RUNNING HANDLER [my_a_or_b_handler] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Handler notified"
}

TASK [Notify if a or b (False or False)] ****
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.stdout_lines": [
        "B is here"
    ]
}

TASK [set_fact] ****
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Notify if a or b (False or True)] ****
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.stdout_lines": [
        "B is here"
    ]
}

RUNNING HANDLER [my_a_or_b_handler] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Handler notified"
}

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=9 changed=2 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

```sh
shell> cat find_a 
#!/bin/sh
echo 'A is here'

shell> cat find_b
#!/bin/sh
echo 'B is here'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I /did/ actually try the `(foo) or (bar)`, but got diverted because my `foo` string had a `:` in it, which threw an error I mistook for something else. Your conviction that this was indeed the right way to go allowed me to focus on different ways of attacking the `:` issue, which turned out to be: `('foo":" thing' in result.stdout) or (bar|bool)`. This works. Your example was excellent. Thank you.

Comment: <offtopic> Also, I discovered that `foo: >` allows you to use all the `: ` you want in your string without further escapes.  :) </offtopic>